# Sub or Function in VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a function or sub to create a report in VBA Excel. I want the user to Enter two dates into two separate text boxes. Then when the submit button is clicked it checks if the text boxes are empty or not then if they aren't it preforms the CreateReport() Sub or function which creates a new sheet and appends data to it. Here is my code:

Userform2:

```
Private Sub Cancel_Click()
 Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub Submit_Click()

If UserForm2.Date1.Value = "" & UserForm2.Date2.Value = "" Then

Value1 = UserForm2.Date1.Value
Value2 = UserForm2.Date2.Value
CreateReport(Value1,Value2)

End If

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Date1.SetFocus
Dim Value1 As String
Dim Value2 As String
End Sub
```

Module1:

```
Option Explicit
Public Function CreateSheet(Name1 As String, Name2 As String)
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim FullName As String
FullName = Name1 & "-" & Name2
Set WS = Sheets.Add.Name = FullName
End Function

Public Sub CreateReport(Date1 As String, Date2 As String)

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you having issues with this code? If so, where? Are there errors, or does it just not produce what you'd expect?

Comment: The only error is that the CreateReport () in the userforum is red.

Comment: Don't make a `Function` if you're not *returning a value* - use a `Sub` / procedure instead.

Comment: Ok but it still is red and I put code into the sub and still red.

Comment: The point is that a `Function` returns a value, a `Sub` doesn't. Also consider properly *indenting* your code when you *write* it, and thank yourself later when you have to *read* it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `CreateReport` when there are no dates entered...

Also

```
CreateReport(Value1,Value2)
```

should be

```
CreateReport Value1, Value2
```

you don't use parentheses unless you're calling a function or using the Call keyword.

And

```
Set WS = Sheets.Add.Name = FullName
```

should probably be

```
Set WS = Sheets.Add()
WS.Name = FullName
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm so use to coding in C++ and other languages I thought you would have to use the parentheses to do the call.